# Преобразование массива в ассоциативный

Tags: php, массивы

Преобразовать массив в котором 1 элемент является массивом ключей, а последующие массивы значений. Пример массива прикрепляю.

Есть массив вида

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => product_id
            [1] => name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => "Николь"
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => Тест
        )
)
```

Нужно сделать

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1
            [name] => "Николь"
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 12
            [name] => Тест
        )

)
```

Comment: И с чем возникли затруднения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сдвиньте массив на 1 элемент - это будут ключи. далее используйте `array_map()` вместе с `array_combine()` для слияния ключей и остатками массива

```
$keys = array_shift($data);

$result = array_map(function($v) use($keys){.
                return array_combine($keys, $v);
            }, $data);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Спасибо) Кратко и точно)

Answer (score 2):

```
$a = [
    0 => ['product_id', 'name'],
    1 => [1, "Николь"],
    2 => [2, "Тест"]
];

$fields = $a[0];

unset($a[0]);

$r = [];
$i = 0;
foreach($a as $values)
{
    foreach($values as $key => $value)
    {
        $r[$i][$fields[$key]] = $value;
    }
    $i++;
}

var_dump($r);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо просто сделать обход по старому массиву и создать новый (самый простой пример):

```
<?php
$oldArray = array('......');
$newArray = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($oldArray);$i++){
  $newItem['product_id'] = $oldArray[$i][0];
  $newItem['name'] = $oldArray[$i][1];
  array_push($newArray,$newItem);
}

print_r($newArray);
?>
```